# Pydantic settings mock

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using Pydantic Settings in a FastAPI project, but mocking these settings is kind of an issue. You cannot initiate `Settings()` successfully unless attributes like `ENV` and `DB_PATH`, which don't have a default value, are set as environment variables on your system or in an .env file, which pydantic can access.

This also means that any fixtures are not possible, because if I import any module which uses the settings somewhere in the code, it will be executed before the fixture is able to do its work.

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ENV: str
    DB_PATH: str

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
        case_sensitive = True

settings = Settings()
```

Now, the only solution I came by thus far, is setting the environment variables in `conftest.py` outside any function:

```
import os
os.environ["ENV"] = "production"
os.environ["DB_PATH"] = "path/to/sqlite.db"
```

There has to be some neater solution?
Any thoughts?

#### EDIT:

As for now I fixed it by just putting them in a function in `conftest.py` and immediately executing that one:

```
import os

def set_environment_variables():
    os.environ["ENV"] = "production"
    os.environ["DB_PATH"] = "path/to/sqlite.db"

set_environment_variables()
```

This way it's possible to set the `settings` attributes later on in fixtures or whatever. But at least it won't complain anymore on initiation. If there is any better solution, please let me know.

Comment: I like using [`pytest-env`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-env/) where you set your environment variables in a config file, and they are then set automatically when eunning the tests.

Comment: I went just with the separate function, which I call in conftest.py. `pytest-env` seems neat, but I thought: do I need a separate plugin for that...? I think this works just as well :)

Comment: `pytest-env` **is** the plugin, you just install it. But yes, this works too.